# Which is the best way to swap alpha characters for special characters? (a = !, b = ", c = £, ...)

Tags: php

I am working with an API which takes three letter text inputs, and produces an image with effects.

One of the styles has to have three characters, the middle character must be upper case, the last character must be lower case, but the first character has to be a special character.

I am using PHP to change the second and third characters which is easy enough, (lcase / ucase)

But the first is a little more tricky as the way I would have done it would be 26 `IF` or `CASE` commands... I'm sure there must be a way to do this with an array?

```
A=! 
B="
C=# 
D=$ 
E=% 
F=& 
...
```

Is there a simple way to put both sets into an array and 'swap' the values?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/strtr

Comment: Thats an ordinal relationship; char code for A == 65, (65-32) = 33 which is `"`  - this hold true for all your chars. (i.e. just deduct 32)

Comment: @AlexK. `chr(ord($x)-32)`?

Comment: @AlexK. I thought about that too, but I didn't want to rely on it. I'll give it a try anyway to see if there are any issues.

Comment: Well just run it in a loop and see if its output matches what your after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str_replace()` which accepts arrays. http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php

```
$search = array( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$replace = array( '!', '"', '#', '$');

$result = str_replace( $search, $replace, $content );
```

Comment: Forgot you can use arrays with str_replace. Thank you!